# how do i get the indices of longest consecutive string in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

this is the my below code and i want to get the indices of longest consecutive of the given string value. Below code is written in typescript.

```js
const value: string = 'ABCCCCCDDBEAAA';

function longest(str: string) {
  let max = 0;
  let currentMax = 1;
  let maxRepeteadChar: string = '';
  let idx: number[] = [];  

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let current: string = str[i];
    let next: string = str[i + 1];

    if (current === next) {
      //get the index
      currentMax++;
    } else {
      max = Math.max(max, currentMax);
      currentMax = 1;    
    }
    if (currentMax > max) {
      maxRepeteadChar = current;      
      idx.push(i);
    }
    
  }

  return { max, maxRepeteadChar, idx };
}

console.log(longest(value));
```

Comment: SO isn't a coding assistance workshop. You should ask a very specific question, such as describing how your above code fails and why you can't understand its behavior. Also, there is nothing Typescript about your question, as algorithms are the same Javascript. TS only adds type safety to JS.

Answer (score 2):

```
const string = 'ABCCCCCDDBEAAA'

type StringDescriptor = {
    maxRepeatedChar: null | string, 
    max: number, 
    idx: number
}

;[...string.matchAll(/((\w)\2+)/g)].reduce(
  (biggestMatch: StringDescriptor,  captures: RegExpMatchArray) => {
    const charString = captures[1]
    if (!charString) return biggestMatch
    return charString.length > biggestMatch.max
      ? {
          maxRepeatedChar: charString[0],
          max: charString.length,
          idx: string.indexOf(charString),
        }
      : biggestMatch
      },
  { maxRepeatedChar: null, max: -1, idx: -1 }
);
```

With input string `"ABCCCCCDDBEAAA"`, result is `{maxRepeatedChar: 'C', max: 5, idx: 2}`

It uses a regex to get consecutive characters that are the same, matches on them, then loops over them and checks the length of the match against the current "winner". If it is longer, it will update the desired return value with the new representation.

If there's 2 strings with the same length it will only return one. But it can easily be made to return multiple if needed.

```
const string = 'ABCCCCCDDBEAAAddddd'

type StringDescriptor = {
    maxRepeatedChar: null | string, 
    max: number, 
    idx: number
}

;[...string.matchAll(/((\w)\2+)/g)].reduce(
  (biggestMatch: StringDescriptor[], captures: RegExpMatchArray) => {
    const charString = captures[1]
    if (!charString) return biggestMatch
    const descriptor = {
      maxRepeatedChar: charString[0]!,
      max: charString.length,
      idx: string.indexOf(charString),
    };
    return descriptor.max > biggestMatch[0].max
      ? [descriptor]
      : charString.length === biggestMatch[0].max
      ? [...biggestMatch, descriptor]
      : biggestMatch;
  },
  [{ maxRepeatedChar: null, max: -1, idx: -1 }]
);
```

Here the string `ABCCCCCDDBEAAAddddd` outputs:

```
[
    {
        "maxRepeatedChar": "C",
        "max": 5,
        "idx": 2
    },
    {
        "maxRepeatedChar": "d",
        "max": 5,
        "idx": 14
    }
]
```

If you want to know what was wrong with your solution you basically need to keep track of the indices that represent the current max, separate to the indices of the character string being worked on at a given time.

```
const value: string = 'ABCCCCCDDBEAAAdddddddd';

function longest(str: string) {
  let max = 0;
  let currentMax = 1;
  let maxRepeteadChar: string = '';
  let maxIdx: number[] = []; 
  let idx: number[] = [];  

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let current: string = str[i];
    let next: string = str[i + 1];

    if (current === next) {
      //get the index
      currentMax++;
    } else {
      if (currentMax > max) { 
        max = Math.max(max, currentMax);
        if (maxRepeteadChar != current) {
            maxRepeteadChar = current;
         
            currentMax = 1
            maxIdx = [...idx]
         
        }
      } 

      idx = []
    }

    idx.push(i)

    
  }

  return { max, maxRepeteadChar, idx:  maxIdx};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the question. Deleted my answer and up voted yours.

Comment: No worries! Just remembered i had to add TS to this one 

Comment: @ImranKhan I have edited into also a fix for your own solution :)

Comment: @Yogi It's generous of you two to do other people's work for them, but it hurts the site by encouraging this. If you're doing it as a fast way to gain rep that's not good either. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260647/appropriate-response-for-do-my-job-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823. Notice that the question has two close votes.

Comment: TBH I've been doing it purely for my own enjoyment recently, addicting actually. Some of these types of things are almost like brain teasers to me. I'm unsure on this question if its as "bad" as some of the others I've seen where "no effort" would definitely qualify. Though that would only be the case if he already wrote what was there, and also understood what I said and did not copy+paste. I never will know to some degree. In this question he has already attempted what he wanted to do, its just wrong. I guess this is pretty grey and that's why they haven't added the option yet.

Comment: I just ignore comments like those because that's why we have voting and close buttons. If you find a question interesting then answer it.